# I'm trying to develope in Python a chatbot with nltk library

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, chatbot, nltk-trainer

I'm having problems with "I'm" since I would like that the bot will response to "I'm Sara" with a sentence different from the sentence replying "I'm happy". Does anyone know how to fix it please?
Specifically:

```
    [r"(.*) my name is (.*)",
            ["Hello %2, How are you doing today ?" ]]
```

for the name sentence and

```
    [r"(.*) (great|fine|wonderful|ok|okay)", 
            ["Sounds great, lucky you!", "Good to you", ]]
```

for the feeling.
If I type: "I'm great" the bot replies me "Hello great, how are you today?"

Can you please help me?

Comment: "tired" is not in the `(great|fine|wonderful|ok|okay)` list, so not matching it is a feature.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I got the wrong example, but it's not working also if I type I'm great, it replies me "Hi great, how are you today?"